# Dúvidas sobre relacionamentos no Rails "campo must exists"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migrations

Bom dia,

comecei a estudar o rails recentemente e sempre que vou definir os relacionamentos entre as entidades do meu banco de dados surgem algumas dúvidas.

Na primeira vez, eu criei e defini os relacionamentos nas migrations. Fiz dessa forma:

```
class CreatePrecos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :precos, id: false do |t|
      t.decimal :valor, :null => false
      t.decimal :valor_anterior
      t.string :cod_filme, references: [:Filme, :codigo]
      t.string :id_locadora, references: [:Locadora, :id]

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :precos, [:cod_filme, :id_locadora], unique: true
  end
end
```

A minha ideia é criar uma chave primária composta com os campos `cod_filme` e `id_locadora` e para isso eu crio duas chaves estrangeiras referenciando as duas tabelas. Quando fiz o comando `rake db:migrate` não recebi nenhum erro, mas encontrei um tutorial em que é feito de outra forma.

Nesse tutorial, eles modificam o arquivo de modelo e definem os relacionamentos lá. Desas forma:

```
class Preco < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :locadora
    belongs_to :filme
end
```

E depois que fazem isso, eles adicionam novas colunas às tabelas criando migrations:

```
$ rails g migration add_column_id_locadora_to_precos id_locadora
$ rails g migration add_column_cod_filme_to_precos cod_filme
```

e depois disso eles executam o migrate e da certo. Eu estou tendo problemas quando tento adicionar um preço. Eu já criei registros em locadora e em filme, mas quando tento adicionar um filme recebo o erro:

> ["Locadoras must exist"]

Eu percebi que quando o relacionamento é `belongs_to` o nome da tabela referenciada tem que estar no singular, mas mesmo depois de ter modificado eu continuo recebendo o erro.

Minha dúvida é: eu preciso definir os relacionamentos nos arquivos de migration ou posso deixar pra definir só nos arquivos de model? Eu devo executar um comando para as modificações serem aplicadas depois que modifico os arquivos de modelo? Se alguém puder me passar um passo a passo de como isso deve ser feito ajudaria muito! Acho que estou misturando tudo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá

Você pode fazer o seguinte, nas migrations: 
rails g scaffold preco valor:decimal references:locadora references:filme

Assim o Rails criará a migration e o model preco corretamente dizendo que este modelo se relaciona com locadora e filme, também já criará no seu form, index e view, e referenciará o id das tabelas relacionadas. No model de Locadora e Filme depois você adiciona um has_many: precos.

Respondendo bem sua dúvida, você pode fazer só nos models mas na forma como te explico acima você fará tudo bem certo, abraço.

Abraço espero que te ajude.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada!